# Gutenberg - Shadow settings not available (theme.json)

Tags: block-editor, theme.json

I registered shadows in my theme.json, but the setting options to add the shadows to Blocks doesn't show in the Gutenberg Editor. Only the presets are available as variables in my source code. I have WP version 6.4.2 installed. This is my theme.json code:

```
"settings": {
"shadow": {
    "defaultPresets": true,
    "presets": [
        {
            "name": "Small",
            "slug": "sm",
            "shadow": "0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06)"
        },
        {
            "name": "Medium",
            "slug": "md",
            "shadow": "0 4px  10px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3 )"
        },
        {
            "name": "Large",
            "slug": "lg",
            "shadow": "0 8px  15px 0 rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.3 )"
        }
    ]
},
}
```

Can someone tell my whats wrong? Or is there a problem with WP?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where did you see that screenshot? I don't see any evidence that this feature is available in core yet. It looks like it's not even in the Gutenberg plugin yet: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/57654

Comment: I've seen it here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/global-settings-and-styles/settings/shadow
and here:
https://fullsiteediting.com/lessons/how-to-add-box-shadows-with-theme-json/

Comment: The examples use "version":  2, I don't see that in your code. Did you post your full theme.json file?